# Get the function arguments for unit testing in NativeScript

Tags: unit-testing, nativescript

i'm kinda new to JS and NS but i'm trying to do some unit test with an nativescript app and my onTap function doesn't "start" when called. I think it may come from the arguments of my onTap but i tried to export it and it didn't work. Thanks for helping. (I'm using Jasmine)

My function looks like this :

```
function onTap(args) {  
    let a = 10;  
    exports.a = a;  
} 
exports.onTap = onTap;
```

And my test :

```
var varTest = require('../home/home-page.js');


describe("test_onTap", function() {


  beforeAll(function() {
    varTest.onTap(arguments);
  });


  it("should return true", function() {
    expect(varTest.a).toEqual(10);
  });

});
```

Comment: You mean the onTap function is never called? What arguments you are talking about?

Comment: Yes the onTap function is never called, the **varTest.a** is undefined so my test never pass. The argument from onTap(**args**), it should contains the event data (on tap) but i don't know how to get it.

Comment: Can you setup a sample repo to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: Sorry i don't know what's a sample repo, but what i'm trying to do is to call my onTap function in my beforeAll. But it seems the parameter is incorrect, i don't know how to get it, because **args** isn't defined. My test found the variable **a** but because the function isn't called correctly, **a** is undefined.

Comment: I'm asking you to setup a project on Github with minimal code to reproduce this issue and share the URL here.

Comment: You can find what i'm trying to do here : https://github.com/iCartouch/unitTest/tree/master

Comment: @Manoj have you check the code ? i'm still trying to get the unit test to work, but none worked :(

Comment: I haven't get a chance, thanks for the reminder. I will try to check it out today.

Comment: I checked your code, generally unit test will not involve UI. You would test the functions / methods without involving UI code. You can test your view model and utility functions which will not require UI objects to run tests. E2E tests take care of UI + Functional Components. But if you like to test UI components as part of your unit testing, you can still just that you will have to take care creating the components and passing them as params. For example in your scenario you will have to create the main page programatically and run the test.

Comment: You may refer the [examples](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/tree/master/tests) from NativeScript repo itself.

Comment: I see, thanks i'll try to create the main page to test it. One last thing, do you know how i can trigger a tap with code ?